# How to check for focus of a textbox c# windows 8 app

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

I'm making an unit converter app and I want it that if you put a value in let's say INCHES textbox then the other textbox changes(miles, feet.. etc, EACH UNIT is a different textbox). I'm using text changed event for each textbox. The problem arises when you put a value in let
s say MILES then the text changed event for MILES start making its job but then the text changed event for the others start working as well... and it keeps just computing values and values and values and it never stops. I want to check for focus for example.

```
if (INCHES got focus)
THEN
   //do the conversions and display it in the other textboxes 
   convert inches to miles,feet,etc... 
  // display it in the other textboxes 
   milestxtbox=the conversion from inches to miles.....
```

Like I said if I don't check for focus( and that is the problem I have no idea how to do it for windows store c# app development ) then everyone's textbox is going to start changing values and it won't stop...:/. I hope I was clear enough with this explanation, I'm always bad explaining stuff. So again when I write in a textbox the other textboxes are going to change to the converted values but it won't be an infinite loop of textboxes changing because of textchanged event. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try moving validation to button click,2 textboxes one for the value and
another for the measurement unit and for example a listbox for output like this...

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lstOutput.Items.Clear();//lstOutput is the listbox
     int inches = Convert.ToInt32(txtInches.Text);
     string UnitOfMeasure = txtUnitOfMeasure.Text.ToUpper();
     ConvertToYardsOrFeet(inches, UnitOfMeasure);
}

private void ConvertToYardsOrFeet(int inches, string UnitOfMeasure)
    {
        int Yard = 0;
        int Feet = 0;
        int Inches = 0;

        if (UnitOfMeasure == "Y")
        {
             Yard = inches / 36;
             Feet = inches % 36 / 12;
             Inches = inches % 12;

             lstOutput.Items.Add(Yard + " Yards" + Feet + " Feet" + Inches + " Inches.");

        }

        if (UnitOfMeasure == "F")
        {
            Feet = inches / 12;
            Inches = inches % 12;

            lstOutput.Items.Add(Feet + " Feet" + Inches + " Inches.");
        }
    }
```

this is just an example of course if u want u can add other units